# Find rows in which sum of column values have a specific result

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, subset-sum

I have the following dataframe:

```
     value
0        2
1        3
2       10
3        1
4       12
```

I need to build a formula that identifies which rows that, when values are summed, result is 23.

In this case the output should be something like `[2,3,4]` (10+1+12).
I believe it is something in the permutation/combination field however [the option I found](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/) that led me closer to that target demands an specific length of combinations, and that wouldn't be the case since the combination could be composed of n values (I will never know the exact size of n upfront).

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: isn't this [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)?

Comment: Seems to be something around that indeed, kind of a solver of some sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from pandas import Series
import itertools

s = Series([2, 3, 10, 1, 12])

result = []
for a, b, c in itertools.combinations(s.index, 3):
    combination_sum = s.iloc[[a, b, c]].sum()
    
    if combination_sum == 23:
        result.append((a, b, c))

result
```

you can generalize this and make it into a function for n values.

#### This is how you will generalize it

In example series I have added some more values for better understanding

```py
from pandas import Series
import itertools

s = Series([2, 3, 10, 1, 12, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

def get_column_whose_sum_is(sum_value=23, combination_of_columns=3, data_as_series=s):
    result = []
    for columns in itertools.combinations(data_as_series.index, combination_of_columns):
        combination_sum = data_as_series.iloc[list(columns)].sum()

        if combination_sum == sum_value:
            result.append(columns)
            
    return result

get_column_whose_sum_is(sum_value = 33, combination_of_columns = 4, data_as_series = s) 
#  [(1, 2, 4, 9), (2, 4, 5, 8), (2, 4, 6, 7), (4, 7, 8, 9)]

get_column_whose_sum_is(sum_value = 23, combination_of_columns = 3, data_as_series = s) 
# [(1, 4, 9), (2, 3, 4), (2, 6, 9), (2, 7, 8), (4, 5, 8), (4, 6, 7)]

#for loop to find all combinations possibilities

c=[]
for i in range(len(s.index)):
    c=c+get_column_whose_sum_is(sum_value = 23, combination_of_columns = i, data_as_series = s)

print(c)

#[(1, 4, 9), (2, 3, 4), (2, 6, 9), (2, 7, 8), (4, 5, 8), (4, 6, 7), (0, 1, 2, 9), (0, 1, 4, 7), (0, 2, 5, 8), (0, 2, 6, 7), (0, 3, 4, 9), (0, 4, 5, 6), (0, 7, 8, 9), (1, 2, 5, 7), (1, 3, 4, 8), (1, 6, 8, 9), (2, 3, 5, 9), (2, 3, 6, 8), (3, 4, 5, 7), (5, 6, 7, 9), (0, 1, 2, 3, 8), (0, 1, 3, 4, 6), (0, 1, 5, 7, 9), (0, 1, 6, 7, 8), (0, 2, 3, 5, 7), (0, 3, 6, 8, 9), (1, 2, 3, 5, 6), (1, 3, 5, 8, 9), (1, 3, 6, 7, 9), (3, 5, 6, 7, 8), (0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 9), (0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8)]
```

Be aware that a [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) like that might incur in performance problems even with small samples.

Comment: How do I generalize it? I will never be sure the size of n

Comment: I have generalized everything as per your requirements. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! That's clearer indeed. As far as I understand, next step would be to put that into a for loop running on different combination_of_columns, right?

Comment: I won't be sure the exact size, but I will be sure of the max size

Comment: Sure, I will try it in a few mins

Comment: in the function you should use "=" not ":", also the data_as_series variable is not mentioned within the func

Comment: well my bad, I did it in hurry !! :D  And for using `:` that is used for intellisese purpose only  if you don't want it you can remove it !! :)

Comment: hey !! pls considering accepting the answer if it helped you !! :)

Comment: just tested it, I'm getting the following error: IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds. Any idea?

Comment: show me your entire code, only than I can figure out the error or at least give me the entire traceback. -- the code I sent you is working fine though !